# Office URI Scheme | Cannot use save location in Office 365

Tags: office-365, word, document-template

I have used the Office URI scheme successfully in the past to perform actions such as:

- **Open** an **instance** of a document template (template.dotx -> New Document.docx)
- Provide a suggested **save location** (when the user clicks save, it will pick a specific site and library by default)

Example:

```
ms-word:nft|u|https://contoso/letter.dotx|s|https://contoso/testlib
```

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes):

> New Document from Template

> The following command will cause the
> application to create and open a new document based on the template
> stored at the specified URI. The template file is not modified in this
> process. An additional command argument may be supplied to specify the
> default path offered as a save location when the file is first saved.
> It is possible for the user to choose a different location.

My tests seem to show that the **save location** parameter is now being **completely ignored** and I get OneDrive as my default save location.

Has anyone else noticed this? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is ackward.

After additional testing, it does seem to work.

Obviously I had to post it here to immediately find a solution :p

There are 2 paths:

**Path #1**

1. click the save icon on the top of the window
2. when promted with the "save this file" dialog click "More options"
3. click browse

**Path #2**

1. click "File"
2. click "Save As"
3. click "Browse"